# no shutdown or restart possible in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shutdown, reboot, ubuntu-mate

I have an Acer Aspire E17 installed Ubuntu 18.04 together with Windows 10
my Windows 10 broke down because I was not using Windows frequently I decided to make a new installation from disk for Ubuntu 20.04 only without windows
Now my computer is not able to shut down or restart
I did update and upgrade and dist-upgrade nothing helps

[screenprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsboW.png)

Answer (score 0):

after  months of research i found out that the mangement of the power supply button has a conflict with management of graphic cards

if /boot/grub/grub.cfg contains

nomodeset
result: power button is operating regularly
shut down works with automatic power off and restart also works.
But then I have only one monitor

For more monitors( I have 3) I decided to have
nouveau.modeset=1 instaed of nomodeset
result all 3 monitors running but power switch not operating automatically

Next try
nouveau.modeset=0 nvidia-drm.modeset=1
result all 3 monitors running and power switch operating

--> Nouveau driver can't replace original nvidia-driver which was target of nouveau

Maybe that helps somebody!

Comment: Do you have any proof to back this up?

Comment: is it on me to proof that ? Iam simple glad that my power button is operating again.